# Texture not shown in UV/Image editor

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I don't know how to make my texture appear in the UV/Image Editor view so that I can transform my unwrapped mesh in order to fix it. I am rather sure that there is a simple button that I did not press but I couldn't find it so far.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]